# Is possible to use variable to define the stdout on bash?

Tags: bash

Currently I am using a logic that detects if a script is run within a cron or a tty, so when run in a tty the script output is presented on screen, and when the script is run as a scheduled task the output goes to a file.

So far the only way I've found to deal with this is by using eval, but using eval is discouraged in case alternatives exists.
So my question is, are there any alternatives to this code?

```
#!/bin/bash
#Var to store interactive session
INTERACTIVE=0
LOG=/tmp/test.file

if [ "$INTERACTIVE" -eq 1 ]; then
    OUT=" 2>&1"
else
    OUT=" &>> $LOG"
fi

echo "Test string!" $OUT #will output "Test string! &>> /tmp/test.file"
eval echo "Test string!" $OUT #will write to the file
```

Comment: A simple system test for interactive mode is `[ $- = *i* ]`

Comment: _"when the script is run as a scheduled task the output goes to a file."_ -- don't make the things complicate. Let the script always send its output to `stdout` and/or `stderr` and add the redirection to file in the cron file. This is the most flexible way and the script can be used in multiple ways and scenarios.

Comment: Just wanted to leave a note, both solutions from KamilCuk and user000001 would fix my issue, I had spent too much time looking for this before asking here, so, thanks to you all :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is possible to use variable to define the stdout on bash?

No, it is not possible. Instead, redirect stdout.

```
if [ "$INTERACTIVE" -eq 1 ]; then
    exec 2>&1
else
    exec 1>>"$LOG" 2>&1
fi
```

Or, write a wrapper function:

```
if [ "$INTERACTIVE" -eq 1 ]; then
    out() { "$@" 2>&1; }
else
    out() { "$@" 1>>"$LOG" 2>&1; }
fi

out echo "test string!"
```

Comment: Hi, I'm marking your reply as the accepted, I just changed my script and it's working perfect

Answer (score 2):

Use `/dev/stdout` to get the standard output:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#Var to store interactive session
INTERACTIVE=0
LOG=/tmp/test.file

if [ "$INTERACTIVE" -eq 1 ]; then
    OUT="/dev/stdout"
else
    OUT="$LOG"
fi

echo "Test string!" >> "$OUT" 2>&1
```

Comment: hi, your solution is great, I'll be using  @kamilCuk because it's more convenient for me currently, thanks for your help